# Efficiently design method to construct a Java GUI?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

This is for a school project where we implement a GUI for our previously made system, problem is our teacher only taught us JFrame.

So in the end, what I have is, a JFrame for the MainScreen, and when I click a button to go the the OtherScreen, it will simply close one screen and open another, in the default position, which isn't ideal obviously :

```
// @ MainScreen :
otherScreenButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        MainController.otherScreen();
    }
});

// @ MainController :

public void otherScreen(){
    mainScreen.setVisible(false);
    otherScreen.setVisible(true);
}
```

My question is, how programmers go about doing GUIs? Adding JPanels inside a main JFrame and setting them visible/not visible on demand? *If someone could also provide a link with more detailed information that would be great.*

Comment: There are several ways: using tabbed panes instead of JPanels, create dialogs, using CardLayout. Everything depends in your needs. Also note that applications have usually only one JFrame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [CardLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html), it will help you with 'switching screens'.

[Here's](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) the documentation.

Comment: That is really helpful, but if I have 10+  JPanel classes to add to the main JFrame with CardLayout, how would I go about doing it with low coupling?